# How to match nested patterns with QRegularExpression?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I'm trying to get with a QRegularExpression all one-line comments starting by a '#'.
I use globalMatch and and an iterator but it doesn't manage to find the "nested comments".

I use this regex :   #[^\n]*

And with the following code :

```
const QString text { "Here # A test with some #comments" };
const QRegularExpression pattern { "#[^\n]*" };

QRegularExpressionMatchIterator it = pattern.globalMatch(text);
while (it.hasNext())
{
    const QRegularExpressionMatch match = it.next();
    qDebug() << match.capturedTexts()[0];
}
```

It founds only the global comment starting at "# A test" and not the second one.
Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: What if you use `"#[^#\n]*"`?

Comment: The pattern `"#.*$"` will be more relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
const QRegularExpression pattern { "(?=(#.*))" };
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator it = pattern.globalMatch(text);
while (it.hasNext())
{
    const QRegularExpressionMatch match = it.next();
    qDebug() << match.captured(1);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qliM7s/2)

BTW, with [`QRegularExpressionMatch::captured`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html#captured), you can directly get the value of any capturing group you need.

The `(?=(#.*))` pattern is a positive lookahead that tests each position inside the input string from left to right, and captures into Group 1 a `#` followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Note that unlike `QRegExp`, `.` in the `QRegularExpression` does not match line breaks, so `[^\n]` can safely be replaced with `.`.

Comment: Not bad ! :)
But it doesn't return "# A test with some #comments" and "#comments",
only "# A test with some " and "#comments".

I think I can fix it programmatically but is it the only way ?

Comment: @Maluna34 So you want to get `# A test with some #comments` and `#comments`? Well, you may concat the two but let me see.

Comment: Wouah incredible ! I didn't think that it was possible !! Thanks !!